# How does the Facebook's video call works

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, flash, audio

How does the Facebook's video call works? Does it use **Flash**, **HTML5**, **Javascript** libraries, or something like that, and how does Facebook's video call detects the strength of the audio or the loudness of it, see the screenshot for example

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking front end implementation then, it can be any language (Java, Python etc.) but if you are curious about backend then read following link...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol

**Here are few points:**

1. For video call there should be a session established between end
   user and for maintaining this session, it uses *Session Initiation
   Protocol(SIP)*.
2. SIP works in conjunction with several other application layer protocols that     identify and carry the session media like `SDP`, `RTP`, `RTCP`.
3. Media identification and negotiation is achieved with the *Session Description Protocol (SDP)*. For example - codec negotiation
4. For the transmission of media streams (voice,video) SIP typically
   employs the *Real-time Transport Protocol (RTP)*. RTP delivering audio and video over IP networks.

Comment: could you please add some image or flow diagram to elaborate.